# Exportar html y mostrarlo en la pagina

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

Buenas estoy itentando exportar es decir mediante la etiqueta inmput type se pueda seleccionar un archivo xml en la web y luego lo muestre, no se muy bien como se puede hacer por ahora solo he logrado importar xml es decir que el xml este en nuestra carpeta del servidor.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    th,
    td {
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <h1>Pagina de XML</h1>

    <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Importa un ejemplo de ficha de pez</button>
    <br><br>
    <p></p>
    <table id="demo"></table>
    <br>
    <button onclick="esconder()">Esconde la importacion</button>


    <script>
        function loadDoc() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    myFunction(this);
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "fichapez.xml", true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
        function myFunction(xml) {

            var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
            var table = "<tr><th>Nombre,</th><th>edad,</th><th>color</th></tr>";
            var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("acuario");
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

                table += "<tr><td>";//Con TR creamos las filas y con td creamos las columnas o celdas
                table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("nombre")[0].textContent;
                table += "</td><td>";
                table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("edad")[0].textContent;
                 table += "</td><td>";
                  table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("color")[0].textContent;
                  table += " ";
                  table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("color")[1].textContent;
                  table +=" </td></tr> <tr><td> ";


                 table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("nombre")[1].textContent;
              
                  table +=" </td><td> ";  
                  table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("edad")[1].textContent;
                 table +=" </td><td> ";  
                  table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("color")[2].textContent;
                 table +=" </td></tr> ";  

                /*table += "<tr><td>";
                table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("pez")[1].textContent;^*/
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
        }


        function esconder(){
            var p="";
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = p;
        }

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Quizás el método [`open` de `window`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) de pueda servir, si es que tu HTML es un fichero de tus assets o lo tienes hosteado en algún sitio.

Comment: Tengo la funcion de importar ahora lo que querria hacer es mediante el input file se pueda cojer cualquier xml desde la pagina y mostrarlo